# ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? errors pretty printing info

Tags: docker

When I run docker info I see this error :

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.12.1)
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc., v0.0.3)
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc., v0.2.13)
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc., 0.6.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.21.0)

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

Can you help me ?

I run docker image hello-world.

Comment: Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: Also, include what operating system you're using.

Answer (score 0):

First check the Docker daemon,if running or not. Then

```
gpasswd -a $USER docker
```

The gpasswd command is used to administer /etc/group, and /etc/gshadow.